# Client error (AuthFailure) occurred when calling the DescribeInstances operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I am getting the following error when trying to run flightplan to push to staging.

I have a colleague who is using this exact git repo and the same credentials and his works, but mine is throwing this error. Any idea why mine isn't working? Is there something I need to install?

```
Benjamins-MBP:XXXXXXX-deploy Ben$ fly --flightplan web-flightplan.js staging --keyfile=/Users/Ben/.ssh/XXXXXX-web-key-pair.pem
Fetching instances for group: 'XXXXXXX-staging-web'

A client error (AuthFailure) occurred when calling the DescribeInstances operation: Authorization header or parameters are not formatted correctly.
● Error: Command failed: /Users/Ben/git/XXXXXX-deploy/app/../scripts/get_aws_instances XXXXXXX-staging-web

A client error (AuthFailure) occurred when calling the DescribeInstances operation: Authorization header or parameters are not formatted correctly.

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:441:13)
    at execSync (child_process.js:481:13)
    at Object.module.exports.fetch (/Users/Ben/git/XXXXXXX-deploy/app/instance-fetcher.js:11:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Ben/git/XXXXXXX-deploy/web-flightplan.js:40:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
```

Client code for describeinstances op:

```
#!/bin/bash

GROUP=$1
if [ -z "$GROUP" ]; then
    echo "Specify group as only parameter"
    exit 1
fi

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

. $DIR/aws_keys
. $DIR/aws_region_us

aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:group,Values=$GROUP"
```

Comment: Need more detail.  Can you paste the client code that is attempting the DescribeInstances operation?  And verify that you have the appropriate SDK/CLI installed to run that operation?

Comment: @AnthonyNeace How would I check that I have the SDK/CLI installed? I can run aws ec2 describe-instances at it works, does that validate it? Client code is in the question now

Comment: The error you are getting usually means that your AWS credentials file is incorrectly formatted or contains invalid information.  Can you run any AWSCLI commands directly, outside of flight plan?  Also, you could try running the AWSCLI command with the ``--debug`` option to see where it is finding the credentials.

Comment: @garnaat I can run aws ec2 describe-instances and get the correct return. Running the flightplan command with --debug doesn't give me any more info.

Comment: So, even if you add the ``--debug`` option to the ``aws ec2 describe-instances`` call inside the describeinstances op you show above, you don't get any additional output?

Comment: @garnaat nope, nothing extra